# Node.js source code getting sent over to client

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building with Node.js locally and I came along a weird problem where if I typed `localhost:8080/server.js`, the whole server-side source code shows up in the browser (the server file's name is `server.js`). I guess what's happening is the server looks for `server.js`, finds itself in the directory and sends it over. That's a huge security risk right? Any way to solve it?

All my code files are present in the same folder; would changing that be the best way to fix the problem?

Comment: "That's a huge security risk right?" — Yes.  "Any way to solve it?" — Remove whatever code you wrote, but didn't provide in the question, which is causing it to do that.

Comment: @Quentin well the server currently just looks for whatever file that's requested, and sends it over if it finds it, else throws a 404 error. I should probably set up some function that checks whether the file is permitted to be sent over.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I'm not using Express, just routing using basic `http`, `fs`,  `url` and `path` modules.

Comment: @edddd — Then the directory you use for the root of the website probably shouldn't be the directory where you keep all your source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since index.html and server.js are in the same folder then the server will send server.js when requested because it thinks it's javascript code for the client and not the server.

You should put the files you want to serve in sub folder (usually named public) like this:

public/index.html
public/style.css

then start the server using that folder with:

`app.use(express.static("public"))`